# React: Are keys reassigned when the underlying data-structure has been changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React. Currently trying to understand how the Reconciliation-process works.

I've got this map-function in my JSX:

```
render: function () {
          var currentIssues = this.state.issues.map(function(issue, i) {
            return (
              <Issue key={ i } ... </Issue>
            );
          });   
          return ( ... )
```

I know that one should add a key-attribute to every child-element. So that React can execute update-, delete-, insert-operations reliable.

Now, let's say I've got five issue-elements in my array. I delete the second element.

Will be render-function be executed again?

The new order will become: 0, 1 (former 2), 2 (former 3), 3 (former 4) ?

Or will the structure be: 0, 2, 3, 4 ?

Comment: If you're modifying `issues` and subsequently calling `setState` with the new val, then yes, you'll force a `render()`. As for the value of `key`, which looks to be the index of your array (`i`), it'll always be sequential.

Comment: If you're adding/removing items from the array you should *definitely* not be using the index as they key. Use `issue.id` if you have one or I think passing the whole `issue` object to key is fine, but I'm not super-sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, when updating a list, for each item in the list, React will check if an item with that key already existed. If it does, it'll update that DOM node, if not it will remove the DOM node. So, it generally doesn't make sense to use the index as a key. Instead, use a unique identifier for the item or just pass in the whole item.

The check that it performs for each element ([source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/shared/shared/shouldUpdateReactComponent.js#L40)) is actually pretty simple.

The actual [reconciliation code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactChildReconciler.js#L137) that runs over all children is a bit more complex, but if you're curious...